# Python - checking if graph is connected - unexpected loop behavior

Tags: python, class, loops

I am coding graph objects (vertex, edge, graph) in Python. I have a `random_graph` method which takes a list of vertices, and for each pair of vertices it places an edge between them with probability `p`. I have a `is_connected` method which returns whether or not a graph is connected.

I want to know the probability that a graph will be connected, given that it has `n` vertices and used probability `p` for random generation. This can be found *without* code, but I want to also calculate this experimentally *with* code, by generating a bunch of random graphs and seeing how many of them are connected.

Everything seems to work fine when I do this once: create a random graph and then check if it is connected. For example, I run the file over and over with probability 0.95 and every time it tells me the graph is connected, as it should with high probability. The problem is that **when I put this same code into a loop to run it many times, the behavior changes**. When in a loop, the (0-indexed) 3rd and 9th iteration print out that the graph is not connected.

Below is all my code, including `play.py` in both forms (non-loop which works and loop which gives the weird behavior):

```
*****
play.py (non-loop, works)
*****

from vertex import SimpleVertex
from edge import SimpleEdge
from graph import SimpleGraph


vertices = []
for i in xrange(10):
    vertices.append(SimpleVertex('v'+str(i), i))

g = SimpleGraph.random_graph(vertices, p=1)

res = g.breadth_first_search(vertices[0])

print 'g is connected:'
print g.is_connected()


*****
play.py (loop, weird behavior)
*****

from vertex import SimpleVertex
from edge import SimpleEdge
from graph import SimpleGraph


for j in range(10):

    vertices = []
    for i in xrange(10):
        vertices.append(SimpleVertex('v'+str(i), i))

    g = SimpleGraph.random_graph(vertices, p=1)

    res = g.breadth_first_search(vertices[0])

    print 'g is connected:'
    print g.is_connected()


*****
edge.py
*****

class SimpleEdge(object):
    """
    Base class for edges of graphs with no concept of direction
    """
    def __init__(self, v1, v2):
        if v1 == v2:
            raise Exception("Cannot make edge from " + str(v1) + " to itself.")
        self.vertices = {v1, v2}

    def __str__(self):
        vertices = list(self.vertices)
        return "Edge(%s, %s)" % (vertices[0], vertices[1])

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.vertices == other.vertices


*****
vertex.py
*****

from edge import SimpleEdge


class SimpleVertex(object):
    """
    Base class for vertices of graphs with no concept of direction
    """
    def __init__(self, name='', vid=None):
        self.name = name
        self.vid = vid if vid is not None else id(self)
        self.edges = []

    def __str__(self):
        display = self.name if self.name else self.vid
        return "Vertex(%s)" % display

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.vid == other.vid

    def has_edge(self, edge):
        """ Checks if a certain edge already exists on this vertex """
        return edge in self.edges

    def add_edge(self, other):
        """ Adds an edge from this vertex to another vertex """
        edge = SimpleEdge(self, other)

        if self.has_edge(edge) or other.has_edge(edge):
            raise Exception(str(edge) + " already exists.")

        self.edges.append(edge)
        other.edges.append(edge)
        return edge

    def neighbors(self):
        """ List of vertices adjacent to this vertex """
        neighbors = []
        for edge in self.edges:
            vertices = edge.vertices
            for vertex in vertices:
                if vertex != self:
                    neighbors.append(vertex)
        return neighbors

    def degree(self):
        """ Number of neighbors this vertex has """
        return len(self.neighbors())

    def breadth_first_search(self, goal=None):
        """ Beginning at this vertex, perform breadth-first search to find the
            distance, in edges, to either some goal vertex or all vertices
            reachable from this vertex """
        vertex_queue = [(self, 0)]
        seen_so_far = set([self])
        dists = {}

        # handle each vertex until there are no vertices left to check
        while vertex_queue:
            next_vertex, current_dist = vertex_queue.pop(0)

            # if searching for a specific vertex, check if this is it
            if goal is not None and next_vertex == goal:
                return current_dist

            # if this is the first time seeing this vertex, store its dist
            if next_vertex not in dists:
                dists[next_vertex] = current_dist

            # put this vertex's neighbors onto the back of the queue
            new_dist = current_dist + 1
            for n in next_vertex.neighbors():
                if n not in seen_so_far:
                    vertex_queue.append((n, new_dist))
                    seen_so_far.add(n)

        # if searching for a specific vertex, it was not reachable
        if goal is not None:
            return -1
        return dists


*****
graph.py
*****

from edge import SimpleEdge, DirectedEdge

import random


class SimpleGraph(object):
    """ Base class for graphs with no concept of direction """
    def __init__(self):
        self.vertices = set()
        self.edges = set()

    def __str__(self):
        vertices_str = ", ".join([str(vertex) for vertex in self.vertices])
        edges_str = ", ".join([str(edge) for edge in self.edges])
        return "Vertices: %s\nEdges: %s" % (vertices_str, edges_str)

    def num_vertices(self):
        """ Number of vertices in this graph """
        return len(self.vertices)

    def num_edges(self):
        """ Number of edges in this graph """
        return len(self.edges)

    def has_vertex(self, vertex):
        """ Checks if a certain vertex already exists in this graph """
        return vertex in self.vertices

    def has_edge(self, edge):
        """ Checks if a certain edge already exists in this graph """
        return edge in self.edges

    def add_vertex(self, vertex):
        """ Adds a vertex to this graph """
        if vertex.degree():
            raise Exception(str(vertex) + " has neighbors.")

        if self.has_vertex(vertex):
            raise Exception(str(vertex) + " already exists.")

        self.vertices.add(vertex)
        return vertex

    def add_edge(self, v1, v2):
        """ Adds an edge between two vertices in this graph """
        edge = SimpleEdge(v1, v2)
        if self.has_edge(edge):
            raise Exception(str(edge) + " already exists.")

        self.edges.add(v1.add_edge(v2))
        return edge

    def average_degree(self):
        """ Average number of neighbors vertices in this graph have """
        if not self.num_vertices:
            return 0
        return 2.0 * self.num_edges() / self.num_vertices()

    @classmethod
    def random_graph(cls, vertices, p=0.5):
        """ Generate a graph using a set of vertices where each pair of vertices
            has some probability of having an edge between them """
        graph = cls()
        for v1 in vertices:
            graph.add_vertex(v1)
            for v2 in graph.vertices:
                if v1 > v2 and random.random() < p:
                    graph.add_edge(v1, v2)
        return graph

    @classmethod
    def complete_graph(cls, vertices):
        """ Generate a graph with all possible edges using a set of vertices """
        return cls.random_graph(vertices, p=1.0)

    def breadth_first_search(self, start, goal=None):
        """ Beginning at some vertex, perform breadth-first search to find the
            distance, in edges, to either some goal vertex or all vertices """
        # perform breadth-frist search starting from the specified vertex
        result = start.breadth_first_search(goal)
        if goal is not None:
            return result
        # for all the unreachable vertices, add them to the result
        for vertex in self.vertices:
            if vertex not in result:
                result[vertex] = -1
        return result

    def is_connected(self):
        """ Checks if this graph has a path from any vertex to any other
            vertex """
        dists = self.breadth_first_search(list(self.vertices)[0])
        return all([dists[dist] >= 0 for dist in dists])
```

Comment: One way to understand what's going on is to generate your random graphs with edge probability `1` and dump all the generated graphs. Now take a look at what graph's `3` and `9` were and why they aren't connected.

Comment: This seems way complex for your task. Do you have to use `class`es?

Comment: You are correct that this is overkill if that were my only task, but I'm actually doing this to practice and for fun, so the whole point is that I'm starting that deep and building up. I originally just wanted to code the graph objects, THEN decided I wanted to do this random graph and connected graph thing.

Comment: Well, don't post so much code when asking questions, or at least show the most relevant code first, and then the rest later in case it's necessary.

Comment: Ok thanks for guidance. I knew it was a lot of code, but since the issue may be in how I coded the classes I anticipated being asked to post that code so I just skipped ahead and did it. And I put play.py first since that's where the change is that causes weird behavior.      Perhaps I could have labeled the rest of the code as "just in case" or waited for someone to ask.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, and can't see any global/class variables or default arguments that would cause the problem. Are you sure it's not just coincidence?

Comment: Hmm, I trimmed some code from the files because I thought it irrelevant, but perhaps I was wrong about that. I will post full files including directed graphs (that's the stuff I left out) later today when I get home (I'm on mobile). Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison of v1 and v2 in SimpleGraph.random_graph is comparing based upon the id of the class, which is probably not what you want.  Adding the following method to SimpleVertex fixes the problem:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.vid < other.vid
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work. I'm not exactly sure why, though. I would have thought that the specific __lt__() method did not matter, because I just wanted to not treat each vertex pair twice, so I just needed *some* order. Why did this change help?

Comment: The `random_graph` algorithm only works as written if the id's are in ascending order.  Vertices added in descending order always fail the `v1 > v2` test.

Comment: Ah shoot. I didn't mean to constrain it like that. Solid catch. I'll make the easy fix.